# Token based authentication

Tags: python, authentication

I am trying to tackle token based authentication to create a simple webapp for login purposes. 
With rest call, I get a token like this below. What would I do after this? So in the server, I have 10 users with passwords, and when a user logs in, he/she would login, and could only login if token matches the username/password in the server. Is this the correct logic? Sample example would be greatly appreciated.

```
"return": [{
    "token": "djfnvk42kfnlsdfk",
 }]
```

Comment: I've answered a similar question before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21300543/authentication-for-node-js-app-with-angular-js-and-ios-clients/22553130#22553130. for Node and Angular. One of your tags says Python, so I can try to answer it more generically if you are not familiar with Node and Angular.

Comment: example in python would help a lot.

Comment: Also depends a bit what you have so far. Do you have a separate client/API? Are you using Django or any other framework? Could you link some of the code you have so far? The more information you give, the better I can answer your question.

Comment: Separate client. It's pulling token from the server using the API(of the server). I am considering Django or Tornado. I just have the part of calling the token.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't seem to have that much setup yet, I'll give you the idea behind token based authentication with some example code:

The idea is that you authenticate the user once by checking if the username and password match (e.g. login). After that you return a security token which identifies this client. The easiest then is to have the client send the token in the HTTP header with every request he makes. You will have to find out how to do this best with the framework that you choose. But it will be something like this:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('<MY_URI>', headers={'Authorization': 'TOK:<MY_TOKEN>'})
```

You will have to remember the clients with tokens that have been authenticated in the back end, so that with every request you can check if the token send is valid. You can then retrieve the token by doing something like:

```
request.META['Authorization']
```

Note that these are just examples, because the implementation will really depend on the framework you choose. There are also quite some implementations and examples out there for different frameworks.

For example for Django:
https://github.com/jpulgarin/django-tokenapi
http://blog.nknj.me/token-authentication-django-and-angular

But you'll be able to find more yourself with Google once you make a decision on the framework that you'll be using.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, rolling your own authentication method is almost always a bad idea unless you are a proficient security researcher. I'm not, that's why I use the builtin authentication in Django REST Framework (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/). It's easy to use, provide a very quick way to spin up a RESTful API, with builtin support for simple token-authentication (what you describe in your question).