# Token based authentication in Tornado

Tags: python, tornado

How can I implement token based authentication for each api call as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22553130/9483467)in tornado.
Where can I store the generated access token for a user as tornado doesn't provides the session-storage mechanism ?

Comment: You can store the tokens in memory (eg, a list, a dictionary, a class), or you can use an external database (eg  Redis).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. let me try